# Get value from form and update table sql

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

i have this form

```
<form method="post" action="{$urls.base_url|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}index.php?fc=module&module=cdesigner&controller=storedata" id="form-submited">
        <input type="hidden" name="link" id="cd-link">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="cd-id">
        <input type="hidden" name="output" id="cd-output">
        <input type="hidden" name="pret" id="cd-pret" value="100">
</form>
```

and this storedata.php

```
class CdesignerStoredataModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->page_name = 'storedata'; // page_name and body id
        parent::init();
    }

    /** Init Function Controller **/
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        if( !is_numeric(Tools::getValue('output')) )
            exit();

        $output = (int)Tools::getValue('output');


        $pret = (int)Tools::getValue('pret'); // this is my edit

        mysql_query("UPDATE ps_customized_data SET price=24 WHERE id_customization=82"); // until here


        $link = filter_var(Tools::getValue('link'), FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $html = filter_var(Tools::getValue('id'), FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

        $myfile = fopen( dirname(__FILE__).'/../../views/img/files/tpl/tp_'.$output.'.html', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $html);
        fclose($myfile);

        echo '
            <script>
                document.location = "'.$link.'";
            </script>
        ';

        exit();
    }
}
```

I'm learning php i'm not a pro.
I want to update the sql table 'ps_customized_data' column 'price' with the value of `<input type="hidden" name="pret" id="cd-pret" value="100">`

I think i have to call sql on storedata.php

Answer (score 1):

To execute a SQL query in Prestashop, you should use [Best Practices of the Db Class](http://doc.prestashop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51184692). Don't use `mysql_query`.

```
// Updating values
Db::getInstance()->update($table, $data, $where = '', $limit = 0, $null_values = false, $use_cache = true, $add_prefix = true)
```

In your case

```
$data = array(
    'price' => $pret
);
Db::getInstance()->update('ps_customized_data', $data, 'id_customization = 82');
```